# Get element in ID by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML:

```
<div id="bin">
    <span class="item1 selectMe">1</span>
    <span class="item2 selectMe">2</span>
    <span class="item3 dontSelectMe">3</span>
</div>
```

I would like to return an array with the values in the span elements which contain the `selectMe` class. This is what I've written:

```
var values = [];
$('#bin span.selectMe').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).text());
});
```

However, when I print `values` to the console, it is always empty. Any thoughts on why I am not iterating through the `bin`?

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: Is your jQuery within a document ready call?

Comment: The javascript is within a function call that. Code later in the function uses the `values` variable. if the jQuery is correct, then perhaps it's another issue. I'm new to jQuery which is why I'm asking...

Comment: If your `var values = [];` line is within that function, then it is a local variable and couldn't be accessed outside of that function. You can move that line outside of the function to create a global variable accessible anywhere.

Comment: Right... the jQuery was correct as stated below but I had my scope off. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9HWwc/) what you posted works fine. Please post a more relevant example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should work, but here is a more elegant solution:

```
var values = $('#bin span.selectMe').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: A simpler selector would be this: `$('#bin .selectMe')`.

Comment: @jfriend00 - If I'd know his exact markup, then you're right. I'm just not sure he's shown us everything, so I used his selector...

Answer (score 3):

The following should work, however what you paste above should seem to also:

```
var values = $('#bin span.selectMe').map(function(){
  return $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [];
$('#bin').find('span.selectMe').each(function() {
     values.push($(this).text());
});
```